# In AIX, how to avoid overwrite a file with cp?

Tags: shell-script, aix, file-copy, gnu

We need to periodically archive some big files older than 2 days to a NAS while keeping their directory tree structure. Those files are kept for 7 days in the source directory.

At first we used `find` for this:

```
find ${SOURCE_DIR} -type f -mtime +2 -exec ksh -c 'mkdir -p $(dirname ${DEST_NAS_DIR}$0) && cp -p $0 ${DEST_NAS_DIR}$0' {} \;
```

However we noticed that the script is copying already archived files, thus each execution takes too much time.

cp doesn't have the -n / --no-clobber option. So, how can I avoid overwriting the same files in destination? any idea?

Regards!

Comment: Can you set the files to be non-writeable?

Comment: use `rsync` instead of `find`+`cp`

Comment: @WhiteOwl Note that `rsync` can't filter by timestamp metadata.

Comment: @Kusalananda, Really? That is a news to me. Then the my eyes deceives me, then I see how rsync is copying just the updated files?

Comment: @WhiteOwl Sure, but how would you tell `rsync` to only copy files that have been modified more than two days ago, which is what the user appears to want to do?  What `rsync` can't do is what `find` does with the `-mtime` test.

Comment: @Kusalananda easy! Just combine rsync with find: `find -mtime +2>list & rsync --files-from list ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `rsync` is available on your system, you may use its `--ignore-existing` flag:

```
find ${SOURCE_DIR} -type f -mtime +2 \
  -exec rsync --ignore-existing '{}' ${DEST_NAS_DIR} \;
```

Possibly the `-u` flag might be interesting - it would check if the sender has newer versions of existing files, too, and update them if so.

See if you want `--archive` mode activated: it means to be recursive and preserve several information regarding times, ownership and more. Check `man rsync` for more details.

Comment: And see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/708267/define-rsync-source-files-as-last-arguments/708272#708272) for a method how to minimize number of rsync program calls.

Comment: This is the method we came around. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You can try to cheat with something like:

```
...yes n|cp -i -p $0 ${DEST_NAS_DIR}$0' {}...
```

Unfortunately I do not have AIX to test it but this will ask for overwrite any existing file and sending "n" will prevent it.

P.S. I do not have currently where to test it so please do it before work with real files.

Comment: Shouldn't we double-quote the variables?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, correct. In my post I just provide a idea how to avoid files overwrite :)