# Define rsync source files as last arguments

Tags: find, rsync, xargs

Say I am using `find` to define **source** files for an `rsync`-operation, making use of special capabilities I only know from these two commands:

```
find /path/to/data -mtime -7 -mtime +5 -exec rsync -aAXu {} /path/to/dest \;
```

However, in this case I cannot use `+` with `-exec` as `rsync` takes the **destination** as last argument.

This means that `rsync` is being called once per matching file instead of creating an argument list and calling `rsync` only a minimum of times.

Same problem appears with `xargs` as I would need the `-I` flag, which implies `-L 1`.

The manual does not seem to show a `--destination-dir=dest` option.

**Is there any simple way to create a `rsync`-built-up command from a list of source files?**

Maybe this is an XY-question and other commands are suited better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call `rsync` with `-exec`, call `sh -c` instead:

```bash
find ... -exec sh -c 'rsync ... "$@" /path/to/dest' sh {} +
```

This calls `sh -c` with an in-line script that simply calls `rsync` in the way you want, with `"$@"` being the current batch of found pathnames passed from `find`.

The trailing `sh` is an arbitrary string that will be placed in `$0` inside the in-line script.  This is necessary since the first found pathname would otherwise be placed in `$0` and therefore not be part of the expansion of `"$@"`.  The value in `$0` is supposed to be  the name of the current shell and will be used in any diagnostic messages generated by the shell.

Comment: Is this save towards "argument list too long" problems? If `$@` takes the maximum number of arguments, `/path/to/dest` might make the argument list longer than allowed - at least what I imagine might be a possible problem.

Comment: @FelixJN Yes.  If `sh -c` is called successfully with a limited set of arguments by `find`, so will `rsync` be called by a limited number of arguments by `sh -c`.  Note also that it's not the _number of arguments_ that is the issue, but the length of the command line, and in this example, that length will not grow between the call to `sh -c` and the call to `rsync` (note that `/path/to/dest` was already part of the command line in the initial call to `sh -c`).